# Superimpose images and create a new image MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

```
im1 = grayscale images
im2 = im2bw(im1, graythresh)
```

Can I superimpose `im1` and `im2` to get a 3rd image with the features from `im1` and `im2` according to a specified interval of `graylevel` ? 
For example, I choose an interval of gray level between 110 and 120. All the pixel from `im1` which have a value between 110 and 120 will keep their initial gray value and all the other one will keep their binary value (from `im2`).

I'm new to matlab.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to threshold using `im2bw`?
If not, I would recommend something like this (using your example threshold values):

```
im1(im1<110) = 0;
im1(im1>120) = 255;
```

Every value below 110 will be set to zero, every value above 120 will be set to 255 (maximum gray level) and the rest remains uneffected.
I hope this is your wanted result. You do not need to superimpose images.

If you really want to use `im2bw` (uses a more advanced threshold method) and superimpose the images `im1` and `im2` you can go with this:

```
im1(im1<110 | im1>120) = 0;
im2(im1>=110 & im1<=120) = 0;

im3 = im1 + im2uint8(im2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tough to do in Matlab, see this example:

```
range = [90 150];
grayThresh = 115;

im1 = imread('rice.png');
im2 = (im1 > grayThresh) * 255;

im3 = im1;
binaryPlaces = im1 < range(1) | im1 > range(2);
im3(binaryPlaces) = im2(binaryPlaces);

imshow(im3);
```

The hardest part is keeping track of what data type each of your images are. If the image is a `double`, then 0 is black and 1 is white, but if the image is a `uint8`, then 0 is black and 255 is white. Because the test image `rice.png` (included with Matlab) loads as a `uint8`, we need multiply to im2 by 255.